# UIPageViewControllerに固定ボタンを追加したい

Tags: swift, swift3

UIPageViewControllerを使用して横スワイプで画面遷移させることはできたのですが、今後画面の上部に固定ボタンを追加して、そのボタンでも画面遷移できるようにしたいと考えておりますが、実装方法が不明のため、ご教授願います。

■用意したファイル
FirstViewController.swift（中身はデフォルトです）
SecondViewController.swift（中身はデフォルトです）
ThirdViewController.swift（中身はデフォルトです）
PageViewController.swift（UIPageViewControllerクラスを継承したファイル）

■実装コード
PageViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setViewControllers([getFirst()], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.dataSource = self as UIPageViewControllerDataSource //追加
    }

    func getFirst() -> FirstViewController {
        return storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    }

    func getSecond() -> SecondViewController {
        return storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    }

    func getThird() -> ThirdViewController {
        return storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

//以下追加
extension PageViewController : UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if viewController.isKind(of: ThirdViewController.self) {
            // 3 -> 2
            return getSecond()
        } else if viewController.isKind(of: SecondViewController.self) {
            // 2 -> 1
            return getFirst()
        } else {
            // 1 -> end of the road
            return nil
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if viewController.isKind(of: FirstViewController.self) {
            // 1 -> 2
            return getSecond()
        } else if viewController.isKind(of: SecondViewController.self) {
            // 2 -> 3
            return getThird()
        } else {
            // 3 -> end of the road
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

■現状の画面
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■現状のMain.storyboard
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■実現したい画面
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■参考にしたサイト
https://qiita.com/Takeshi_Akutsu/items/dbf54df8e8a50e8ed5be

Comment: @dokubeko 様、コメント誠にありがとうございます。また、質問の範囲が曖昧で大変申し訳ございません。私自身iOSの知識が乏しいため、このような質問になってしまいました。ただ、「カスタムコンテナビューコントローラ」というアドバイスを頂き、大変参考になりました。「カスタムコンテナビューコントローラ」については、私自身初めての内容で、まだ理解しておりませんので、自分なりに試行錯誤してみたいと思います。貴重なアドバイスありがとうございます。

Comment: また、正しくはページビューの「上部」ではなく「前面」に実装しようと検討しておりました。質問文に曖昧な記述があり、申し訳ございません。